# expression for the integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Let's assume that integral 
$
\int_a^b f(x) \,dx = I
$
is known ( $I$ -- some constant).

Is there any way to express the integral $\int_a^b f(x) e^{-c x}\,dx$ in terms of $I$ ?

Comment: Not for $c \neq 0$. If you add a nonzero $g$ to $f$ with vanishing integral, you don't change $I$, but generally, $\int_a^b g(x)e^{-c x}\,dx \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

use integration by parts technique

$$\int_a^b f(x) e^{-cx}dx =e^{-cx} \int_a^b f(x)-(\int_a^b \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-cx})(\int_a^b f(x)) $$

for details check out this site: http://www.algebrahomeworkhelp.info/

Comment: I think you mean $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)e^{-cx}dx=\bigg(e^{-cx}\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt\bigg)|_{a}^{b}+c \int_{a}^{b} e^{-cx}\big(\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt\big)=e^{-cb}\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt+c \int_{a}^{b} e^{-cx}\big(\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt\big)dx$

Comment: This solution has serious shortcoming: we must have analytic expression for $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ or, if it is impossible, compute it for inner points of interval $(a,b)$